# How to deal with like clause with special char like _,\,% in jooq

Tags: java, jooq

I'd like to use sql with special char to search list such as
select * from test where name like "%_%" but this will also search - and _,
so how can I deal with it?
and how about char % or ?

Answer (score 1):

Just like in native SQL using [`escape()`](https://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org.jooq/org/jooq/LikeEscapeStep.html#escape(char))

```java
TEST.NAME.like("%!_%").escape('!')
```